# Flexslider thumbs with arrow on top

Tags: css, thumbnails, css-shapes, flexslider

I'm using Flexslider on a project and need to make it look like the image bellow: 
[image]

This is what I came up with so far **[SEE DEMO](http://creativmouse.com/slider/)**

The only thing missing is that blue arrow on top of the active thumbnails. I've managed to get the blue border but just can't figure out how to place an arrow on top.

Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div id="smallslider" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
          <li data-thumb="images/thumb1.jpg">
          <a class="sliderlink" href="#"> 
          <div class="smallslider-thumb"><img src="images/small_slide1.jpg"></div>
          <div class="smallslider-header">Infra Red Dedo LEDzilla Onboard light <span>Lighting for Hire</span></div>
          </a>
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="images/thumb2.jpg">
          <a class="sliderlink" href="#"> 
          <div class="smallslider-thumb"><img src="images/small_slide2.jpg"></div>
          <div class="smallslider-header">Infra Red Dedo LEDzilla Onboard light <span>Lighting for Hire</span></div>
          </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#smallslider .flex-control-thumbs li {
    width: auto;
    margin: 6px 12px 0;
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:        border-box;
}
#smallslider .flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
    opacity: 1; cursor: default;
    border: 4px solid #2a80b9;
    margin: -2px;
}
#smallslider .flex-control-thumbs {
    margin: 32px 50px 0;
    position: static;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#smallslider .slides img {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}
img.flex-active {

}
```

Comment: perhaps this could help: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work